# How to extract text from a table in a .docx file?

Tags: python, docx, python-docx

I want to extract the text from a table that is in a .docx files using python for further analysis. Im using the following code:

```
document = Document(path_to_your_docx)
tables = document.tables
for table in tables:
    for row in table.rows:
        for cell in row.cells:
            for paragraph in cell.paragraphs:
                print(paragraph.text)
```

But it seems there is another "table" in the cell of this table, so I'm not able to extract this part (shown in the attached image). When I use the code above, I can't fetch the "Yes/No" text.

I have tried also to iterate through the cells as if in a table, but I get the error that the cell doesn't have table attribute. Any advice?

[The table looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36Pyf.png)

[code behind table creation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNoM8.png)

Thanks.

Comment: Please do not paste screenshots of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a workaround for this issue. Instead of using the library **python-docx** to extract the text from the docx file, I used the library **docx2txt** (extract **all** the text) and then I just needed to find the specific word in the string.

```
text = docx2txt.process(file)

q = "Example1"
result = text[text.find(q)+len(q):].split()[0]
```

and this gives me the "Yes" or "No" from Column2, for each value on Column1 (In the example above, it gives **Yes**).

Comment: That works, but docx2python will extract the tables. That nested table will need some post processing, but the output is clearly described in the docs.